# JSON Date format (without time) returning from an API

Tags: json, node.js, datetime, date-formatting

Wondering if I should remove the time data normally stored. We're using `postgres` and `node.js` where a DateTime would get returned from our API as:

`2013-07-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Yet since this field should only represent a date, I feel reformatting before return like this would make it more clear that time is not relevant:

`2013-07-01`

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Got this problem too. Create user table with birthday column, date type. So, it should only has date (without time). Get time when query with node-postgres.

Answer (score 6):

If you are representing a calendar date, there is no time or timezone.  The short representation makes more sense.

Unfortunately, new Date(string) in many javascript implementations can do [bad things](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) to you.

```
new Date('2015-09-23')
Tue Sep 22 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

The simplest way out of the problem is not to use javascript's Date - this type matches up with DateTimeOffset in other languages.  It is a bad way to represent calendar date values.

But, you're probably going to use javascript's Date anyway.  The next simplest "fix" is to avoid standard representations (since standard representations get interpretted as DateTimeOffset with UTC).  Here are two possibilities:

Use "/" instead of "-".

```
new Date('2015/09/23')
Wed Sep 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Use a 3 digit month - the leading zeroes will be discarded.

```
new Date('2015-009-23')
Wed Sep 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

If you have javascript on the both the client and server side, you're done.  If you have something else on the server side, you should consider what the server language will do if it sees non-standard date formats coming in.

Answer (score 1):

As an API user, I would much rather receive the long form of a date.

For a few reasons:

1. **Time Zone**: the long format actually has a time-zone built in. That's important.
2. **Parsing**: most languages will be able to read that long format as a native "Date" object. In some languages like C# & Java, that short date will need to be coerced into using the correct time zone. You also avoid Month/Day confusion with the long format.
3. **Comparisons**: if a user passes *in* a short date, is your API going to handle that correctly? A good API needs to look the same going in and out.

Comment: Sure, but the time zone is not relevant in a date. The time zone makes things bad (e.g. if my birthday is January 15 1900, it is also January 15 1900 in China, even though time zones may affect that.)